# RabbitMQ Direct reply-to and Correlation Id

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using the RabbitMQ [Direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) feature for my RPC calls and I'm using Correlation Id as it mentions [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html).

My question is do I need to use the Correlation Id if I'm using the Direct reply-to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reply-to` value is known to be unique (it looks like `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkAA9yYWJiaXRAbWVyY3VyaW8AAAFJAAAAAAI=.41Feb1a6XK29NG5/qnF24w==`), so using `correlation-id` is not mandatory, but you MAY keep using if you plan to switch back from [Direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) for some reason.